# ng repeat start / end in Angular 2

Tags: angular, ngfor

Before I could do something like this in Angular 1.x :

```
<tbody>
    <tr class="resource-row" ng-click="expandRow(resource.id)" ng-repeat-start="resource in resources track by $index">
        <td>
            <a ng-bind="resource.id"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat-end="" class="resource-sub-row" ng-show="resource.expand">
        <td colspan="4">
            <div class="resource-details" ng-repeat="details in resource.details">
                <div class="stream-data form-inline col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label>Resource Details: </label>
                        <div>{{resource.level}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

This allows for the expand and collapse row to be repeated.

edit: please note ng-repeat-end is on the second tr element, allowing for pairs of tr elements to be repeated. If I didn't add the  ng-repeat-start and end, I would not be allowed to use the second ng-repeat inside the resource-details element. ngFor does not allow for this behavior the same setup as angular 1.x

How can I accomplish this in Angular 2.0.1?

Comment: take a look at [angular 2 docs](https://angular.io), you could easily replace `ng-repeat` with `*ngFor`

Comment: Please read through the entire html snippet. ng-repeat-end is on the second tr element, allowing for pairs of tr elements to be repeated. If I didn't add the  ng-repeat-start end, I would not be allowed to use the second ng-repeat inside the resource-details element. ngFor does not allow for this behavior the same setup as angular 1.x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out after realizing I was using the wrong syntax.

So use the `<template>` element like so to achieve ng-repeat-start/end behavior

```js
</template ngFor let-resource [ngForOf]="resources">
    <tr class="resource-row" ng-click="expandRow(resource.id)">
        <td>
            <a ng-bind="resource.id"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="resource-sub-row" ng-show="resource.expand">
        <td colspan="4">
            <div class="resource-details" *ngFor="let details of resource.details">
                <div class="stream-data form-inline col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-12 form-group">
                        <label>Resource Details: </label>
                        <div>{{resource.level}}</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```

Note the `*ngFor` on the `.resource-details` element inside the second `tr`.

Everything works great.